# Filling the parent with Qt widgets

Tags: qt4, expand, qt-designer

I'd like to create an application's main window in qt4 designer.

When I add a layout element to the `centralwidget`, that element stays in the middle of the window and does not move when the window is resized. How can I make it "fill" the whole area (and resize its children properly)? All children widgets of my layout are expanding properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you add the element, select the main window, and click one of the layouts (from the toolbar), so that it gets applied to the main window's children.

Comment: Toolbar == the real top one, not the one on the left, which is the widget panel by default. <- this took me some time to discover :)